# Given the following table of class probabilities, find the TPR and FPR at thresholds 0.78 and 0.53

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, roc

Below is a table of tuples that contain class probabilities for a ROC curve. How can I compute the TPR (True Positive Rate) and FPR (False Positive Rate) at the thresholds 0.78 and 0.53?

[image: Table of probabilities]

Note: the solutions to TPR(0.78) = 0.4, and FPR(0.53) = 0.6. I'm just not sure how to find them (or the missing two).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TPR(0.78) = 0.4 because at a cut off of 0.78, there are 2 values correctly identified as positive out of the total 5 positive values (2/5). The FPR(0.53) = 0.6 because there are 3 negative values incorrectly identified as positive out of 5 total negative values (3/5).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for--that makes so much sense. Thank you so much!